# Let $G$ be finite and every nonidentity element have prime order. If $Z(G)\neq\{e\}$, prove that every nonidentity element of $G$ has the same order.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

[This question appears to be new here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nontrivial+center+prime+order+elements)

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra,"* by Gallian.

This is Exercise 4.51.$^\dagger$

> Suppose that $G$ is a finite group with the property that every nonidentity element has prime order (*e.g.*, $D_3$). If $Z(G)$ is not trivial, prove that every nonidentity element of $G$ has the same order.

*Thoughts:*

> **Lemma:** If $G$ is abelian with the property that every nonidentity element has prime order, then every nonidentity element has the same prime order.

*Proof:* If $G$ is abelian (*i.e.*, $G=Z(G)$), then consider $g,h\in G$ such that $\lvert g\rvert=p$ and $\lvert h\rvert=q$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$. We have

\begin{align}
(gh)^{pq}&=(g^p)^q(h^q)^p\\
&=e,
\end{align}

so that $\lvert gh\rvert$ divides $pq$.

If $\lvert gh\rvert=pq$, then it is composite, a contradiction; thus without loss of generality $\lvert gh\rvert=p$. Now we have

\begin{align}
e&=(gh)^p\\
&=g^ph^p\\
&=eh^p \\
&=h^p,
\end{align}

but now $q\mid p$, which is a contradiction since $p\neq q$ and $p$ is prime.

Thus all nonidentity elements of $G$ have the same prime order.$\square$

---

That's all I have so far.

I've considered proving some version of the contrapositive but nothing springs to mind other than, "yeah . . . contrapositive might work" followed by a shrug.

---

*Edit:*

[This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075645/let-g-be-finite-and-every-nonidentity-element-have-prime-order-if-zg-neq#comment6341003_3075645) gives me some idea of how to finish; however, I'm not sure where the finiteness of $G$ comes into play.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$ I've just noticed that this exercise has a solution in the book. It makes sense to me. If anyone would like to answer it here anyway, go ahead! <strike>I might post an answer later summarising the proof in the text.</strike>

Comment: How about mimicking the abelian proof with one general element of the group and one nontrivial element of the center?

Comment: I see what you mean, @Mindlack! That's a fun little trick! Thank you.

Comment: But . . . Why is finiteness necessary, then, in the original exercise? @Mindlack.

Comment: @Shaun They might just be trying to avoid awkward questions like "is infinity prime".

Comment: I haven't considered such a question before, @user3482749. (Well, I don't remember doing so at least.) Which infinities have a property analogous to that of primality?

Comment: @Shaun They don't. The problem is that it's kind of an awkward edge-case definition thing, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone just ruled out the infinite case to avoid having to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following paraphrases the proof in the solutions section of the book the exercise is from.*

Let $z\in Z(G)$ such that $\lvert z\rvert=p$ for a prime $p$. Consider $g\in G$. We have $\lvert g\rvert=q$ is prime. Then

\begin{align}
(zg)^{pq}&=(z^p)^q(g^q)^p \\
&=e^qe^p \\
&=e
\end{align}

and thus $\lvert zg\rvert\in\{p, q\}$ (since it has to be prime; and if $\lvert zg\rvert=1$, then $z=g^{-1}$, so $p=q$). Assume without loss of generality that $\lvert zg\rvert=p$. Then

\begin{align}
e&=(zg)^p \\
&=z^pg^p \\
&=eg^p \\
&=g^p,
\end{align}

so $q\mid p$. Hence $p=q$.

Comment: Why can’t $|zg| = 1$, i.e how do you know that $zg \neq e$?

Comment: Since $|zg|$ has to be prime (and $1$ is not prime), @Junglemath.

Comment: Every nonidentity element has prime order. Why can't $zg = e$?

Comment: I see now, @Junglemath. Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing selfstudy and studying Group Theory, and using Gallian's book. Today I encounter this problem. I spend almost 2 hours on the problems and didn't find a clear path. So I thought to take some help (hint) from MSE, and so I reached at your question. After reading your question I found where my knowledge lack. Actually the part where you showed **p and q are distinct by contradiction**, here I was not getting contradiction. 
Now I have wrote my proof without looking at the back of the book (solution). Please have a look.

**Proof:** Suppose $Z(G)$ is not trivial. Suppose $x \in Z(G)$ and $y \in G$ are both non-identity elements. Let $|x|=p$ and $|y|=q$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $p$ and $q$ are distinct. Since $(xy)^{pq} =e$, it follows $|xy|$ divides $pq$. If $|xy|=pq$ then a contradiction because $pq$ is composite. WLOG assume $|xy|=p$. Then $e=(xy)^p=y^p$, so $q|p$, a contradiction. Thus $p$ and $q$ are equal. Since $p$ and $q$ were arbitrary, therefore every non-identity element of $G$ has same order.  ∎

**Edit**: I just have looked at your accepted answer and solution in the book. I found I have missed a case in which order of $pq$ is equal to one.